# Symfony Security get back to referer page after login

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to set up my security, so it redirect back to referer after login.

For example, i am opening /profile/{slug}

This is my ProfileController

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request, $slug)
    {
    $authChecker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');

    if(!$authChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
       return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fos_user_security_login'));
    }

    $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $userManager->findUserByUsername($slug);

    if(!$user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Пользователь не найден');
    }

    return $this->render('AppBundle::profile.html.twig', array('user' => $user));
    }
}
```

If user is not logged in, controller redirects to login route.

After user logged in, it is being redirected to home page. I want to change it to referer.

Here is my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4
                login_path: /account/login
                check_path: /account/login-check
                use_referer: true
            logout:
                path: /account/logout
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

As you see, i have added use_referer: true there, but it is not working.

How should i do then?

Comment: Do you have a redirect when user is logged in? Did you clear you cache?

Comment: Im not so dumb, to not clear the cache..